# Filtering data in controller by drop downs of view

Tags: ajax, grails, groovy, filter

I have a large dataset, which I am trying to filter in the controller itself and send only the relevant data to the view ( index.gsp; client side)

**View1:**

```
<form>
   <g:select from="['AFFILIATES', 'SEO', 'SEM','DISPLAYADS']" name="mv"
      onchange="${remoteFunction(
      controller:'Pgtyp', 
      action:'ajaxGetMv', 
      params:'\'mv=\' + (this.value)',
      onSuccess: 'printpgtyp(data)')}">
   </g:select>
</form>
```

**Controller1:**

```
def ajaxGetMv = {
   def pgtyp = Pgtyp.executeQuery("select p.visits,p.mv from Pgtyp p where p.mv = ?",[params.mv])
   //console.log(params.id)
   render pgtyp as JSON
}
```

Now, this part works perfectly after printing on console, it's filtering data for specific "mv".
But, I have multiple drop downs(5) which are independent to each other, I want all these 5 values passed to my controller always and then filtered data accordingly to come to the view, but I am not able to implement this.

I implemented it using "html - document.getElement " but the data is too heavy to be handled on the client side(browser crashes)
Hence, I need the filtering to happen on the groovy controller side.
I tried for 2 filters via 2 drop downs :

**View2:**

```
<form>
   <g:select from="['AFFILIATES', 'SEO', 'SEM','DISPLAYADS']" name="mv"
      onchange="${remoteFunction(
      controller:'Pgtyp', 
      action:'ajaxGetMv', 
      params:'\'mv=\' + (this.value)',
      onSuccess: 'printpgtyp(data)')}">
   </g:select>
</form>

<form>
   <g:select from="['INTERNET EXPLORER', 'MOZILLA', 'GOOGLE CHROME','MOZILLA' ,'OTHERS','SAFARI']" 
     name="browser"
     onchange="${remoteFunction(
     controller:'Pgtyp', 
     action:'ajaxGetMv', 
     params:'\'browser=\' + (this.value)',
     onSuccess: 'printpgtyp(data)')}">
   </g:select>
</form>
```

**Controller2:**

```
class PgtypController {
   def ajaxGetMv = {
     def pgtyp = Pgtyp.executeQuery("select p.visits, p.mv, p.browser from Pgtyp p where p.mv = ? and p.browser = ?",[params.mv & params.browser])
     render pgtyp as JSON
   }

   def index() { }
}
```

**Error:**

```
POST http://localhost:8082/marchmock2/pgtyp/ajaxGetMv 500 (Internal Server Error) 
send 
x.extend.ajax 
onchange
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Also, let me know if this is not feasible in grails, but I think it mostly should be.

Comment: Are you calling same controller for for both ajax call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
[params.mv & params.browser]
```

to

```
[params.mv, params.browser]
```

in your `hql` query (Controller2).

---

Yes you are getting filtered data. A list of list(contains p.visits, p.mv, p.browser). You can get the p.visits like

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '${createLink(controller: 'myController', action: 'myAction')}',
    success: function(data){
        for (var idx = 0; idx <= data.length - 1; idx++) {
            console.info(data[idx][0])    
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I modified it, error is gone. Thanks!
Now, in the console it's printing : [each: function, eachSlice: function, all: function, any: function, collect: function…]   - And if I open this, there is "length" and "__proto__ :Array[0]" , if I expand the latter, there is a whole list of variables.

But, I need to access the "p.visits", which I am selecting in my controller. How do I do that? And is this filtered data that I am getting?

Comment: Made the edits, but the console is not printing anything yet. also, the file sin the network are of same size. If the file is actually being filtered, the size must be different, so it doesn't look like it's filtering.

Comment: What do you mean by filter, may be I am on wrong track?

Comment: So I have a large dataset, which I am trying to filter by making index and controller talk using ajax and remotefunction in grails. For only one dropdown, it works perfectly. Now, when the user selects the 2nd or the 3rd dropdown, the data should be filtered further with the new values of 2nd (or 3rd) dropdown and also the static value of 1st dropdown (which did not change now).

Comment: Similarly, there are 5 dropdowns and data that comes to browser should be filtered for any of the 5 selections which are made, we need to pass the value of 5 filters simultaneously to the controller, irrespective of whether it changed or not. I was trying more options like " params:'\'param1=\'+this.value+\'&booleanParam2=true\''  "

Comment: How do I pass multiple parameters in the index.gsp simultaneously ? ( there will be 5 dropdowns passing 5 parameters, 1 dynamic and 4 static in each)

Comment: you can get the value of a field by `id` or `class`. id gives you first occurrence and class gives you all the occurrences. So fives a class to all 5 selects e.g., `myFilterSelects` then send values like: `params:'\'browser=\' + $(".myFilterSelects").val()',`

Comment: Your data is filtered: in your controller2 you get the data which satisfies both the conditions.

Comment: Ok, great. But what exactly do I add in the **myFilterSelects** , do I add all the document.getElementbyId of the dropdowns here?

Comment: `<g:select class='myFilterSelects' ...` then `document.getElementsByClassName('myFilterSelects')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57097/discussion-between-user2063493-and-user1690588).